# About an exercise in Functional Analysis using the Uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For $x=(x_i)$ and $y=(y_i)$ two sequences in $\mathbb R$, we define

$$<x,y>:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_iy_i$$

if possible.
Let $1<p<+\infty$, $q=pq-p$ and $x^{(n)}=(x_i^{(n)})$ a sequence in $\ell_p$. I am trying to show that the following two facts are equivalent:

1. $\forall y\in\ell_q \ <x^{(n)},y>\to 0$.
2. $\exists K>0:\|x^{(n)}\|_p\leq K \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N$ and $x_i^{(n)}\to 0 \ \ \forall i\in\mathbb N$.

---

***$(1)\Longrightarrow (2)$***. Let $e_i=(0,\dots ,0,1,0,\dots )$ where $1$ is in the $i$-th place. We have that:
$$<x^{(n)},e_i>=x_i^{(n)}\to 0$$
Now, we define the sequence of functions $T_n:\ell_q\to\mathbb R \ $ as $ \ T_n(y)=<x^{(n)},y>, \ \ y\in\ell_q$.

- $T_n, n\in\mathbb N$ are well defined. By Holder inequality we have that $$\left |\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i^{(n)}y_i \right | \leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}y_i|\leq \left (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}|^p\right )^{1/p} \left (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|y_i|^q\right )^{1/q}$$
  Let $\epsilon>0$. 
  $$x^{(n)}\in\ell_p\Longrightarrow \exists n_1\in\mathbb N: \ \forall n\geq n_1 \left (\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}|^p\right )<(\sqrt{\epsilon})^P$$
  and 
  $$ y\in\ell_q\Longrightarrow \exists n_2\in\mathbb N: \ \forall n\geq n_2 \left (\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|y_i|^q\right )<(\sqrt{\epsilon})^q$$
  So, $\forall n\geq n_0=\max\left \{n_1,n_2\right \}$
  $$\left (\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}y_i|\right )\leq ((\sqrt{\epsilon})^p)^{1/p}((\sqrt{\epsilon})^q)^{1/q}=\epsilon$$
- It is obvious that $T_n,n\in\mathbb N$ are linear.
- $T_n,n\in\mathbb N$ bounded. Form Holder inequality we arrive to
  $$\forall y\in Y \ \ |T_n(y)|\leq \|x^{(n)}\|_p\|y\|_q$$
  and so $\|T_n\|\leq \|x^{(n)}\|_p$. It, moreover, holds that $\|T_n\|= \|x^{(n)}\|_p$. We know that 
  $$ \|T_n\|=\underset{y\in\ell_q\setminus\left \{ 0 \right \} }{\sup}\frac{|T_ny|}{\|y\|_q}$$
  Now, for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we define $y^{(n)}=(y_i^{(n)})$ as $y_i^{(n)}=sign(x_i^{(n)})|x_i^{(n)}|^{p-1}$. We have that $y^{(n)}\in\ell_q$, since 
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|y_i^{(n)}|^q=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}|^{qp-q}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}|^p<\infty$$
  Moreover, 
  $$|T_ny^{(n)}|=\left |\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i^{(n)}sign(x_i^{(n)})|x_i^{(n)}|^{p-1} \right |=\left | \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}||x_i^{(n)}|^{p-1} \right | = \left | \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}|^p \right |=\|x^{(n)}\|_p^p$$
  and 
  $$\|y^{(n)}\|_q=\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(n)}|^p \right )^{1/q}=\left (\|x^{(n)}\|_p^p \right )^{1/q}=\|x^{(n)}\|_p^{p/q}$$
  so we conclude that
  $$\|T_n\|\geq \|x^{(n)}\|_p^{p/q-p}=\|x^{(n)}\|_p$$
- To summarize, we have a sequence $(T_n)$ of bounded linear functionals in $\ell_q^*$ (where $\ell_q$ is of course Banach) with the following property:
  $$\forall y\in\ell_q \ \ T_ny=<x^{(n)},y>\to 0$$.
  From the Theorem of Uniform Boundedness we conclude finally that 
  $$\exists K>0: \ \|T_n\|=\|x^{(n)}\|_p\leq K \ \forall n\in\mathbb N$$.

---

I am having trouble proving the inverse. All my ideas fail and I cannot find a way to use the uniform boundedness of $x^{(n)}$. Here is one of my starting ideas, let $y=(y_i)\in \ell_q$,
$$\forall i\in\mathbb N \ \ x_i^{(n)}\to 0 \Longrightarrow \forall i\in\mathbb N \ \ x_i^{(n)}y_i\to 0 \Longrightarrow \forall k\in\mathbb N \ \ \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i^{(n)}y_i\to 0$$
How can I continue taking the limit $\lim_k\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i^{(n)}y_i$ and see that it goes too to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $y\in\ell^q $, there exists  $j_0$ such that  $$\left (\sum_{j>j_0}|y_j|^q\right)^{1/q}<\frac\varepsilon{ K}. $$
Then
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_jx_j^{(n)}y_j\right|
&\leq \sum_j|x_j^{(n)}y_j|=\sum_{j=1}^{j_0}|x_j^{(n)}y_j|+\sum_{j>j_0}|x_j^{(n)}y_j| \\ \ \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^{j_0}|x_j^{(n)}y_j|+\|x^{(n)}\|_p\,\left (\sum_{j>j_0}|y_j|^q\right)^{1/q}\\ \ \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^{j_0}|x_j^{(n)}y_j|+\varepsilon .
\end{align}
So, as $x_j^{(n)}\xrightarrow [n]{}0$,
$$
\limsup_n \left|\sum_jx_j^{(n)}y_j\right|\leq\varepsilon. 
$$
And $\varepsilon  $ was arbitrary, so
$$
\lim_n \left|\sum_jx_j^{(n)}y_j\right|=0.
$$